# iMessage Extension - I can not interact with UICollectionView until I try to swipe to another app and then come back

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, imessage

The view is loaded, cells are shown, everything looks fine, but when i click on a cell, or try to scroll down, nothing happens. When I swipe to the left or right and try to switch to another app, the view becomes responsive and reacts to touches and scroll. I don't have to switch to another app completely, just swipe (drag) my app view a little to the left or right, and the collection view becomes responsive. Any ideas? :)

Thanks

Comment: When the view is loaded, wait for a few seconds, and then interact with it. This happens in iMessage Apps. We faced similar problems while building it. If it doesn't resolve it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I see this when debugging, but not standalone. The simulator is the worst offender, but it happens on-device as well.

If debugging, I've noticed the extension becomes usable when the memory resource gauge in Xcode is populated. Until then everything seems frozen.

[image]